# How to horizontally scale a Spring Security OAuth2 Client?

Tags: spring, spring-security, openid, spring-security-oauth2, okta

Spring Security OAuth2 Client uses HttpSession to store the access token if we use oauth2Login() to obtain the access token from Okta (Authorization server). That will force us to have only a single instance of OAuth2 client and won't be able to horizontally scale in an environment like Kubernetes.

To solve this issue I was able to find different approaches on the internet.

1. Use implicit flow where the access token is obtained and maintained in the browser client which is less secure to the above approach.
2. Once you obtained the access token in the backend, produce a new custom JWT token with all the claims copied and store it in the user's browser. So every subsequent request can be authenticated using that JWT token thereafter.
3. Use the Spring-Session library to share the HttpSession between multiple OAuth2 client instances and stick to plain old HTTP sessions to store access token.

What would be a better approach?